# C# activate manual a event

Tags: c#, event-handling

i have a Button with a click event in the background.
Can i use this method in another timer triggered event?

```cs
 private void bt_Disconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        {
            if(ser.disconnect())
            {
                img_Ampel.Source = ampeln[0];
                bt_Connect.IsEnabled = true;
                bt_Disconnect.IsEnabled = false;
            }

        }
```

Thats the click event.
The following snippet is the timer trigger.

```
private void polling_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!serial_port.IsOpen)
        {
            mw.Show("Die Verbindung ist abgebrochen!", "Bitte schließen Sie das Gerät wieder an uns klicken Sie auf Verbinden.");
            polling.Stop();
            MainWindow.bt_Disconnect_Click();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to to raise the `Click` event of a button you can use [`PerformClick()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.performclick?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method of button.

```
yourbutton.PerformClick();
```

> This method can be called to raise the Click event.

Answer (score 2):

Separate logic and event handling.
The simplest way is to extract method:

```
private void DoSmth()
{
    if(ser.disconnect())
    {
        img_Ampel.Source = ampeln[0];
        bt_Connect.IsEnabled = true;
        bt_Disconnect.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}

private void bt_Disconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoSmth();
}

private void polling_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!serial_port.IsOpen)
    {
        mw.Show("...");
        polling.Stop();
        DoSmth();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stefan: because 99.99% OP doesn't want to raise an event, but wants to reuse some code, which already presents in `Click` handler.